# How to suppress azure cache client warnings from the WAD logs

Tags: caching, azure, azure-caching

We have 2 roles which use a cache role to share data.  When we deploy we get many many of the following entries in the logs:

```
INFORMATION: <CASClient> Updated partition table to (1-901) generation: 635036190744461419:0 with transfer (1-901) generation: 635036190744461419:0; TraceSource 'w3wp.exe' event

INFORMATION: <Complaint> Add hard complaint :0 ; TraceSource 'w3wp.exe' event
```

Changing the values of the setting:

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ClientDiagnosticLevel" value="0" />
```

seems to have no effect.

Any ideas how we can remove this noise from the WADLogs table?

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is a bug in Caching (see this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/7ebbc44e-7b61-4bbe-aa54-a85a7788079f)). I tried to get rid of these log entries with no luck running SDK1.8. Recently I switched to SDK2.0 but unfortunately the problem is still not fixed.

[Bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/156)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be adding a filter for this.

**Sample for web.config:**

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
        <listeners>
            <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener">
                <filter type="Namespace.TraceFilter, Assembly" initializeData="Information"/>
            </add>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Note: The attribute `initializeData` is set to the text from `System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels` enum. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705160/746674).

**TraceFilter.cs**

```
public class TraceFilter : EventTypeFilter
{
    public TraceFilter(SourceLevels level)
        : base(level) {}

    public override bool ShouldTrace(TraceEventCache cache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, string formatOrMessage, object[] args, object data1, object[] data)
    {
        return !Regex.IsMatch(formatOrMessage, "INFORMATION: <[^>*]*>");
    }
}
```

You could extend this to a more generic filter which could run off a configuration accepting different patterns to include/ignore.

Comment: Phil did this work for you?  We're getting the same issue on the latest SDK (v2.2) with the `ClientDiagnosticLevel` not being taken into effect and your solution looks ideal as a work around

Comment: @Click-Rex the concept was sound and when testing locally, the filter was being hit. It's a suitable workaround but I keep telling myself to read up more on the azure diagnostics, especially the configuration to ensure I'm using them properly.

Answer (score 1):

After reading a suggestion at the end of [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/156) we managed to disable this by running the following code in the application:

```
DataCacheClientLogManager.ChangeLogLevel(TraceLevel.Off);
DataCacheClientLogManager.SetSink(DataCacheTraceSink.DiagnosticSink, TraceLevel.Off);
```

This stops all logging from the Azure Cache Client without you having to turn off your own `Warning` or `Information` level logs.

We ended up adding this in the constructor of our Cache Provider wrapper around the DataCacheClient:

```
public class AzureCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
    public AzureCacheProvider()
    {
        DataCacheClientLogManager.ChangeLogLevel(TraceLevel.Off);

        DataCacheClientLogManager.SetSink(
            DataCacheTraceSink.DiagnosticSink, 
            TraceLevel.Off);

        InitializeCache();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution

Just make sure to use your namespace and corresponding assembly name.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    /*
     Solves the Azure In-Role Cache client warnings bug which is too verbose in the WAD logs
     Also Solves Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener not using Filter

     For roles which uses in-role caching, configure your Web.config or app.config with the following system.diagnostics listner and filter:
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace>
            <listeners>
                <add name="AzureDiagnostics" type="MyNamespace.FilteringDiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, MyAssemblyName">
                <!-- WARNING: does not work with type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                              because the DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener does not call the filter's ShouldTrace method as is was supposed to... -->
                <!-- Note:    working with type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" -->

                    <filter type="MyNamespace.SuppressCacheClientWarningsTraceFilter, MyAssemblyName" initializeData="Information"/>
                    <!-- Note: The attribute initializeData is set to the text from System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels enum. -->
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
     */

    /// <summary>EventTypeFilter which suppress the 'noise' messages from the In-Role Azure Cache client
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>It's a workaround for the following problem http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/7ebbc44e-7b61-4bbe-aa54-a85a7788079f/complaint-add-hard-complaint?forum=windowsazuredata.
    /// The solution is based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443856/how-to-suppress-azure-cache-client-warnings-from-the-wad-logs and http://pastebin.com/qKc1aTTW
    /// </remarks>
    public class SuppressCacheClientWarningsTraceFilter : EventTypeFilter
    {

        public SuppressCacheClientWarningsTraceFilter(SourceLevels level)
            : base(level) { }

        public override bool ShouldTrace(TraceEventCache cache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, string formatOrMessage, object[] args, object data1, object[] data)
        {
            return !(
                        (eventType == TraceEventType.Information && Regex.IsMatch(formatOrMessage, @"^INFORMATION:\ <(CASClient|Complaint)>"))
                        || (eventType == TraceEventType.Warning && Regex.IsMatch(formatOrMessage, @"^WARNING:\ <SimpleSendReceiveModule>\ DeadServerCallback"))
                    );
            //return !Regex.IsMatch(formatOrMessage, @"^INFORMATION: <[^>*]*>");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener which uses the configured Trace Filter
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>It's a workaround for the following problem http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92ed1175-d6b7-4173-a224-0f7eb3e99481/diagnosticmonitortracelistener-ignors-filter?forum=windowsazuretroubleshooting
    /// The solution is based on the thread comment from "Qin Dian Tang - MSFT": "If you need to use trace filter, then it is needed to use a custom trace listener which derives from DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, override TraceData, and either manually check filters or call the root class's (TraceListener) TraceData."
    /// </remarks>
    public class FilteringDiagnosticMonitorTraceListener : DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener
    {
        public FilteringDiagnosticMonitorTraceListener() : base() { }

        public override void TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, string format, params object[] args)
        {
            if (this.Filter == null || this.Filter.ShouldTrace(eventCache, source, eventType, id, format, args, null, null))
                base.TraceEvent(eventCache, source, eventType, id, format, args);
        }

        public override void TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, string message)
        {
            if (this.Filter == null || this.Filter.ShouldTrace(eventCache, source, eventType, id, message, null, null, null))
                base.TraceEvent(eventCache, source, eventType, id, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.